# How to add a wx.BoxSizer border?

Tags: python, wxpython

what is the most simplest way to add a black border around some widgets using the `wx.BoxSizer` property like this image below? i am currently learning how to use box sizer to implement in my application.

[image: Layout with Box Sizer]

Here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/cVzqh86M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the widget inspection tool. It can do outlining. You'll just have to learn how it is doing it and then replicate the code. You can read about it on the [wxPython wiki](https://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20use%20Widget%20Inspection%20Tool%20-%20WIT%20%28Phoenix%29)

The tool comes with wxPython.

Answer (score 0):

You can add border for each element by passing the border parameter

**For example:**

```
label = wx.StaticText(self, label='Border')
hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
hbox.Add(hbox, proportion=2, flag=wx.EXPAND, border=10)
```